# Check existence of joomla session

Tags: session, joomla

I have tried to check sessions existence till user login in Joomla with `JFactory::getSession();` but it's not working.

Also `JFactory::getUser();` this method shows user ID after session lifetime expired. 
Please let me know if any solutions are there to validate Joomla sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the Joomla session

```
$Jsession = JFactory::getSession();
$session = $Jsession->get('myVar');
```

and then perform a check if you wish, like so:

```
if($session) {
    // session exists
}
else {
    // session doesn't exist
}
```

As for showing the user ID, the ID will only show if the users is logged in as `getUser()` retrieves the **current** user object.